# Update a row string using a previous row string in R

Tags: r, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a series of event markers that come in row pairs, for example:

Trial <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Event <- c('S 31', 'S  6', 'S 22', 'S  4', 'S 42', 'S  4')

df <- data.frame(Trial, Event)

```
    Trial Event
    1     S 31
    2     S  6
    3     S 22
    4     S  4
    5     S 42
    6     S  4
```

I would like to update the single digit event by concatenating the double digit event from the previous row, so it looks like this:

```
    Trial Event
    1     S 31
    2     S 316
    3     S 22
    4     S 224
    5     S 42
    6     S 424
```

I'm struggling to think of a way to achieve this, and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

We create a grouping column for every 2 elements using `gl`, then `replace` the last element in 'Event' by `paste`ing the parsed number from 'Event'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n()))) %>%
   mutate(Event = replace(Event, n(), 
     str_c('S', str_c(readr::parse_number(Event), collapse=""),
       sep= ' '))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Trial Event
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 S 31 
#2     2 S 316
#3     3 S 22 
#4     4 S 224
#5     5 S 42 
#6     6 S 424
```

---

Or another option is to paste with the `lag` of the 'Event' while creating a logical condition with `case_when`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(Event = str_remove(case_when(row_number() %% 2 == 0 
         ~ str_c(lag(Event), Event), TRUE ~ Event), "(?<=[0-9])S\\s+"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
   mutate(Event = str_remove(
        case_when(row_number() %% 2 == 0 ~ str_c(lag(Event), Event), 
        TRUE ~ Event), "(?<=[0-9])S\\s+"))
```

@akrun 's solution is very elegant. Mine does basically the same just uses uses more steps to make it simpler to follow.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Exampe data
Trial <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Event <- c('S 31', 'S 6', 'S 22', 'S 4', 'S 42', 'S 4')
df <- data.frame(Trial, Event)
                 


df %>% 
  mutate(
    # extract number from chacater
    str_number = readr::parse_number(as.character(Event)),
    
    # new column with last rows value
    lag_col = ifelse(
      nchar(as.character(dplyr::lag(str_number))) > 1, 
      dplyr::lag(str_number),
      NA),
    
    # joins if has 2 characters
    Event = ifelse(
      is.na(lag_col),
      as.character(Event),
      paste0("S"," ",lag_col, str_number)
    )
  ) %>% 
  select(Trial, Event)
```